# Java String to Type

Tags: java

I have an XML defined which provides a payload path to a serialized XML. I would like to take these parameters and create an object and call a method in a class. What is the best approach to do this in Java?

```
XML
<RequestObjectType>com.test.model.QueryType</RequestObjectType>
<Class>com.test.api.Query</Class>
<Method>generalQuery</Method>


public void callRequestViaObj(String payloadXML, String payloadType, String api_className, String method){
    Class c_payloadType = Class.forName(payloadType);
    Class c_apiClass = Class.forName(api_className);
    JAXBElement<c_payloadType> elemreq = (JAXBElement<c_payloadType>) JaxbUtils.XMLtoObj( payloadXML, JAXBContext.newInstance(c_payloadType) );
    c_payloadType qreq = (c_payloadType) (elemreq.getValue());

    //Would like to do something like this...
    c_payloadType.newInstance().callMethod(method).with(qreq);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the reflection-api:

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/

section "Invoking Methods by Name"

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools that will do this for you.  One of them is [Castor](http://www.castor.org/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to tweak the calls that use the reflection API. Try

```
c_payloadType.newInstance().getMethod(method, qreq.getClass()).invoke(qreq);
```

This assumes that `c_payloadType` is an instance of `Class<?>` and `qreq` is the argument you want to pass to the method call. I'm not sure if the JAXB code you've written correctly constructs those two objects.